# Does a surjection from x to y imply a surjection of their power sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If there exists a surjection $f: X \to Y$ for some sets $X$ and $Y$, does this imply there exists a surjection $g: P(X) \to P(Y)$?

Comment: Suggestion: Consider the set-function $f(A)=\{f(x)\in Y |x\in A\}$ for $A\subset X$

Comment: Suggestion #2: Draw out a Diagram of an arbitrary surjective  map, and then ask yourself the question again. Does each subset of $Y$ have at least one corresponding subset in $X$ (each of whose elements' images correspond with the elements of the particular subset of $Y$)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

If $A\in \mathscr P(Y)$ (so $A \subset Y$), then for each $a\in A$ there exists some $x_a\in X$ with $f(x_a)=a$ (because $a\in Y$ and $f$ is surjective). Put $S = \bigcup_{a\in A}\{x_a\}$. Then $S\in\mathscr P(X)$ (because $S\subset X$) and $f(S) = A$.

We could also just note that $f(f^{-1}(A))=A$, so the set $f^{-1}(A)$ does the trick. In fact, a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective if and only if $f\circ f^{-1} = \operatorname{Id}_Y$.

**Comment:** For the sake of completeness, I add that a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is injective if and only if $f^{-1}\circ f = \operatorname{Id}_X$.